# Error: Keypool ran out, please call keypoolrefill first

Tags: regtest, dash, keypool

After setting the dash-client in regtest mode, I am trying to generate coins.

No matter what I do, I get the above error.

When I run:

```
dash-cli -regtest getmininginfo
```

I get the below output:

```
{
   "blocks": 0,
   "currentblocksize": 0,
   "currentblocktx": 0,
   "difficulty": 4.656542373906925e-10,
   "errors": "",
   "genproclimit": 1,
   "networkhashps": 0,
   "pooledtx": 0,
   "testnet": false,
   "chain": "regtest",
   "generate": false
}
```

How do I set the generate to true.

If I run

`setgenerate true`

I get the message that `setgenerate` is deprecated, on this network I need to use generate which doesn't run.

Answer (score 1):

Unlock your wallet (using `walletpassphrase`) and run `keypoolrefill` as the error message says. `generate` and `setgenerate` requires keys from the wallet, and if the keypool is empty, they won't work.